# Is there any disadvantage wrapping socket.io in a callback function in AngularJs Service?

Tags: angularjs, socket.io

I made a service in angular.js to use socket.io inside my controllers like it were a callback function. In my service the emitter and listener are in the same function, that is what I use in my controllers as follows:

service.js

```
(function () {
/* Socket IO Service */
var service = angular.module('MyService', ['']);


service.factory('sio', ['$http', function($http){

    var socket;
    socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');

    return {
        /* queries  user */
        login: function(authData, callback){
            socket.emit('__app auth login', authData);
            var response = socket.on('__app auth login', function(res){
                callback("", res);
            });
            return response;
        },
        findUser: function(conditions, callback){
            socket.emit('__app user find', conditions);
            var response = socket.on('__app user find', function(res){
                callback("", res);
            });
            return response;
        },
    };
  }]);
})();
```

My controller:

```
(function () {
/* My Controller */
var myController = angular.module('MyCtrl', ['']);

myController.controller('MyController', function($scope, sio){
    var conditions = {username:"john123"};

    $scope.conditions = conditions;
    $scope.message = "Hello";

    this.search = function(){
        sio.findUser(conditions, function(err, response){
            $scope.message = response.status;
            console.log(response);
        });
    }
    $scope.search = this.search;
  });// /--ctrl
})();
```

Everything seems to work. Is there some issue or disadvantage of using it like that? Or should I wrap just the socket.io object in a service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no inherent disadvantage other than potential violation of expected behavior *depending on accepted best practices*.  The question is whether or not are in line with them.

Because the actual WORK (connecting and holding open the connected socket) is being done in a singleton service, you don't have to worry about connections dying.

That said, best practices would dictate that all service-related work should be done IN the service itself.  Does that extend to callbacks on promises?  According to the [John Papa AngularJS Styleguide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#return-a-promise-from-data-calls), promises should be returned from services so that they can be chained in the invoking controllers.

As a result, based on what is currently considered best practice by a large contingency within the AngularJS community, your implementation does not ***not*** meet absolute best practices, although it is completely reasonable.